# Mustache with squared brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mustache

I'm trying to render this template:

```
Mustache.render('{{ user[first_name] }} from {{ country }}', JSON.parse('{"user[first_name]" : "Michael"}'))
```

But am getting this error: `Unclosed tag`

Is there a way to get this working in ruby?